# Iteration among components in talend 5.6

Tags: talend

I have a filename and I have to check if it is there in physical location. If it is there then I have to increment like filename_1,filename_2 etc and check If filename_1 exists in physical location and in database if it is there in any one of these  then increment  again and check in both physical location,database until I get a file name that is not there in both places.

But any link is not going back for iterating though components in talend.

when i found a filename not in both places then i have to create a file with that name in physical location and update in database.

Answer (score 0):

Use these components :

tLoop : for loop, from 1 to 9999 (as infinity)

tFileExists : check for `"filename_"+((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_VALUE"))`

if not exists : write new file with this name `"filename_"+((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_VALUE"))` and update the `tLoop_1_CURRENT_VALUE` beyond the max of the loop to get off the loop, use a `tJava` and this line of code `globalMap.put("tLoop_1_CURRENT_VALUE",9999))`

Dont forget to check the first file `filename` separatly before the loop.

Comment: when i got a file name that is not existing in both places then i have to create that file in a location. By using tLoop it is creating 10 files (i kept max 10) but i need to stop after creating one file.